# How to find chains in time series pandas data frames with start date and end date based on another column's value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
          beginDate     endDate        rating 
id
1         2019-11-05    2020-03-24      2    
2         2020-03-24    2020-08-19      1    
3         2020-08-19    2020-12-31      2
4         2020-12-31    2050-12-31      3
```

I want to be able to detect the chains of ratings values between 1 -> 2 and 2 -> 1 and synthetically add rows to get this new data frame with beginDate of the begining of the chain and endDate of the end of the chain:

```
          beginDate     endDate        rating 
id
1         2019-11-05    2020-03-24      2    
2         2020-03-24    2020-08-19      1    
3         2020-08-19    2020-12-31      2
4         2020-12-31    2050-12-31      3
5         2019-11-05    2020-12-31      1+2
```

Any suggestion on how to do this cleanly and more importantly efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

This makes a lot of assumptions that your data is always sorted correctly, that you are looking for changes in 1 and 2, rather just 1 or 2 ratings, and you don't say if you need this as part of larger dataframe where `groupby` and `apply` would be necessary. This can be adapted into those scenarios:

```
df =  pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''id   beginDate     endDate        rating 
1         2019-11-05    2020-03-24      2    
2         2020-03-24    2020-08-19      1    
3         2020-08-19    2020-12-31      2
4         2020-12-31    2050-12-31      3'''), sep='\s+', engine='python').set_index('id')

# drop ratings 3 and above and find start and end dates, add r       
s = df.loc[df.rating < 3].head(1)['beginDate'].iat[0]
e = df.loc[df.rating < 3].tail(1)['endDate'].iat[0]
r = '1+2'

add_dict = {'beginDate': s, 'endDate': e,  'rating': r}
# append dictionary
df.append(add_dict, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
df.append(add_dict, ignore_index=True)

    beginDate     endDate rating
0  2019-11-05  2020-03-24      2
1  2020-03-24  2020-08-19      1
2  2020-08-19  2020-12-31      2
3  2020-12-31  2050-12-31      3
4  2019-11-05  2020-12-31    1+2
```